# Dynamic form in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

A given Transaction has an Incentive.  Based on the Incentive, there are 0 or more required fields.   The "name" of the field is given by the IncentiveRequiredField.name.  So the relationship is that for each Transaction+RequiredField, there is a unique value.

```
class Transaction(models.Model):
    incentive = models.ForeignKey(Incentive)

class TransactionRequiredField(models.Model):
    transaction=models.ForeignKey(Transaction)
    incentiverequiredfield=models.ForeignKey(IncentiveRequiredField)
    value=models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Incentive(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class IncentiveRequiredField(models.Model):
    incentive = models.ForeignKey(Incentive)
    name = models.CharField(max_length = 100)
```

I think I have this part of the model right, though I'm by no means certain.

The trouble comes when I'm trying to add new Transactions.  I need to be able to show a set of TextInputs, labeled with IncentiveRequiredField.name, after the user selects the incentive from a dropdown.  Those Inputs need to be tied to the TransactionRequiredField model.

I know I will need to use Javascript to accomplish this, and I'm comfortable
with setting up an AJAX call via jQuery to get the list of RequiredFields for a Transaction (given the incentive_id), but I'm totally new to Django (and python in general), so I have no idea how to add that to the Add/Change Transaction view in the Django Admin.

Can someone explain to me (like I'm 5 years old), how I go about this?